# Google Cloud Dataproc - Submit Spark Jobs Via Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Is there a way to submit Spark jobs to Google Cloud Dataproc from within the Scala code?

```
  val Config = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("...")
```

What should the master URI look like?

What key-value pairs should be set to authenticate with an API key or keypair?

Comment: Just to clarify - are you trying to connect from outside of the Google Cloud Platform (like your local computer) or from inside of the Cloud Platform, whether on a machine in the cluster or another virtual machine?

Comment: @James from outside.

Comment: @BAR did you get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'd strongly recommend an alternative approach. This type of connectivity has not been tested or recommended for a few reasons:

1. It requires opening firewall ports to connect to the cluster
2. Unless you use a tunnel, your data may be exposed
3. Authentication is not enabled by default

Is SSHing into the master node (the node which is named `cluster-name-m`) a non-starter? It is pretty easy to [SSH into the master node](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/submit-job#ssh_into_an_instance) to directly use Spark.

Comment: I thought Spark might be copying the necessary code as needed, which is where this question arose from.  But its easy to setup a git repo and push updates, then ssh in and start workers.

Comment: @James, If i am submitting it within dataproc GCP platform, what should be the masterurl set to ?  `SparkConf()
      .setAppName("test").setMaster("???") `

Comment: As alternative option, we can set the master url value to "yarn" , GCP cluster uses YARN cluster NM for this.